# How do I compute the KL divergence in Keras with TensorFlow backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can I compute kl diveregence in keras while using tensorflow as backend? I compute L1 loss as follows:

```
def l1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Keras already has the KL-divergence implemented, as it can be seen [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py#L48), the code is just:

```
def kullback_leibler_divergence(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1)
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1)
    return K.sum(y_true * K.log(y_true / y_pred), axis=-1)
```

So just use kld, KLD or kullback_leibler_divergence as loss.

Comment: What are the expected inputs of this KLD? What do y_true and y_pred mean? I see formulas using Mu and Sigma, but y_true and y_pred aren't those? Should they have some specific shape like ending in 2? Or is there any mathematical trick involved?

Comment: @DanielMöller They should be elements of a histogram representing the probability distribution, this KL does not take mean/std directly.

Comment: So, are they "numerous samples" from the distribution (seems to make more sense and requires nothing special to do) or are they "bins" of the distribution?

Comment: The first dimension is always samples, the second dimension is the bins.

Comment: You should provide a minimal and complete example that shows how to use this loss.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `tf.keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence` function.

If you want to use it as an activity regularizer, you can create a simple regularization function:

```py
import keras # if using keras
# from tensorflow import keras # if using tf.keras
kullback_leibler_divergence = keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence
K = keras.backend

def kl_divergence_regularizer(inputs):
    means = K.mean(inputs, axis=0)
    return 0.01 * (kullback_leibler_divergence(0.05, means)
                 + kullback_leibler_divergence(1 - 0.05, 1 - means))
```

In this example, 0.01 is the regularization weight, and 0.05 is the sparsity target. Then use it like this:

```py
keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="sigmoid",
                   activity_regularizer=kl_divergence_regularizer)
```

For example, this would be the encoding layer of a sparse autoencoder.

Note that the `kullback_leibler_divergence` expects all the class probabilities, even in the case of binary classification (giving just the positive class probability is not enough). This is why we compute the KLD for both 0.05 and 1-0.05 in the function above.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not get your last paragraph, why do we have to compute KL for 1-0.05?? @MiniQuark

Comment: The KL Divergence is a measure of the discrepancy between two probability distributions. Any probability distribution must always add up to one. So a single proba p is not a probability distribution, but [p, 1-p] is. If you only compute kullback_leibler_divergence(target_p, p) then the minimum KLD will be reached when p=1, and the max will be reached when p=0. If instead you compute kullback_leibler_divergence([target_p, 1-target_p], [p, 1-p]) then the KLD will be minimum when p=target_p.
Note that kld([target_p], [p]) + kld([1-target_p], [1-p]) = kld([target_p, 1-target_p], [p, 1-p]).